# Excel VBA pass multiple Combobox values to dynamic array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, combobox

I would like to know if there is a way to add selected multiple combo box values to a dynamic array. So far this my code below, at the moment I can only submit the one selected Combobox value to the array list.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ComboBox1.AddItem "1"
ComboBox1.AddItem "2"
ComboBox1.AddItem "3"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cmbbox(10) As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = LBound(cmbbox) To UBound(cmbbox)
    cmbbox(i) = ComboBox1.Value
    MsgBox cmbbox(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

I would like to be able to select a value from the combo box, and then that value gets passed to my array at the 0 position, and then if the another value is selected from the combo box, then that value is passed to my array's 1 position etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
For Each Item In ComboBox1.List
    If Not Item Then
        MsgBox Item
    End If
Next
```

**Edit:** Did I miss your point here, or did you change your question? According to what I read now, you want to append combobox value at the end of your array each time you hit commandbutton. You should do as follows:

Define your array outside of your sub (at the very top):

```
Dim cmbbox() As Variant
```

and the code should look like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Len(Join(cmbbox, "")) = 0 Then 'if your array is empty add the first value from combobox
    ReDim cmbbox(0)
    cmbbox(0) = ComboBox1.Value
Else 'if your array is not empty redim your array and add value from combobox
    ReDim Preserve cmbbox(UBound(cmbbox) + 1)
    cmbbox(UBound(cmbbox)) = ComboBox1.Value
End If

MsgBox "Last Added Item : " & cmbbox(UBound(cmbbox))
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not Item` what is this check supposed to do?

Comment: if item is not null

Comment: The solution provided by Tehscript is a simpler example of my original loop. But works in the exact same way.

Comment: What? It does nothing like the same as your code - it's iterating a completely different property, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I think the questions is changed. @Ambie the difference between his code and my first suggestion is: his code loops through same selected combobox value 10 (static) times and my code loops trough all combobox values. This was his request at first but now I see a different question which I responded in edit.

Comment: @user1810449 I see you did not mention anything about hitting commandbutton even if you have `CommandButton1_Click` event in your sample code. So if you want your code activated when you select an item from combobox instead of clicking the commandbutton, you should use `ComboBox1_Change()` event instead of `CommandButton1_Click`. Just wanted to answer this before you ask :)

Comment: I updated my question to reflect my intended aim. Thanks for your edited solution Tehscript

Comment: The way it should work is if a user selects any of combo box values "1 or 2 or 3" and they click the add button, the value (whichever) should get added to the first position '0' of the array, if then the user selects another value then that will be stored in the second position '1' of the array, following this pattern to the end of the array.

Comment: In the end I will have an array that will look similar to the example below;
Array position ¦ 0     ¦ 1     ¦ 2    ¦ 3     ¦ 4 ¦......
Array value     ¦ one ¦ one¦ one ¦ two ¦ one ¦......

Comment: The edited code above already does your request if you use it within `ComboBox1_Change()`. If you have any problem with it, please indicate the problem.

Comment: That edited code works a treat in both events (ComboBox1_Change() and CommandButton1_Click()) Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

As @Tehscript has indicated, the property you're after is `.List` which returns a two-dimensional, zero-based array: the first dimension being 'rows' and the second 'columns'.

From your question, it seems as if you want a specific index (or indices) from the row dimension. If your `ComboBox` only has one column then the second dimension could be hard-coded as zero.

A `For Each` loop would be okay, but the problem is that it will loop through every item in the array rather than just each row. It might be more efficient, therefore, to run a `For [index]` loop. Let's say you want the first and third items in your `ComboBox`, then the code snippet would be:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim v As Variant

v = ComboBox1.List
For i = 0 To UBound(v, 1)
    If i = 0 Or i = 2 Then
        MsgBox v(i, 0)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I would like the user to select the value, once selected then that gets added to the Array. This code doesn't quite to do that.

Comment: But that's a totally different question from the one you originally asked! I'm not sure that adding this all-important point by way of edit at the end of your question will get it noticed now, so you might want to ask a new question, acknowledging you worded your previous one wrongly. You might also want to spend time making your question absolutely clear. You already wasted @Tehscript's time and mine, so who's to say that you won't change your question again and waste more people's time. Try to be as clear, concise and specific as you can.

Comment: The question above has been amended accordingly. And it's not really a waste of time, as its all part of the learning curve. By all means if you can help, please do (but don't rant about it).